# Embedded youtube video not showing through iframe & php

Tags: php, html, forms, iframe, youtube-iframe-api

This is a simple html form. I am trying to show a youtube video while taking video link from the user. I use an input field for the link where user enters the link of the video from youtube,
here is the form:

```
<body>
<form action="youtubetest.php" method="post">
    Enter Link here<br><input type="link" name="youtubelink">
    <input type="submit" name="submit">
</form>
</body>
```

From this form I accept the link which is sent through post to youtubetest.php.
Here is the youtubetest.php:

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html> 
<body> 
<?php
$str = $_POST['youtubelink'];
$splittedstring = explode("watch?v=",$str);    //For obtaining video id
foreach ($splittedstring as $key => $value) {

$x[$key] = $value."<br>";
}

$link = "https://www.youtube.com/embed/";
$vid_link = $link.$x[1];   //Concatenation
echo "Video Link is : ".$vid_link;
echo "<iframe src='".$vid_link."' allowfullscreen  height='480' width='500'";

 ?>
</body> </html>
```

please if anyone can sort out the issue. I'm trying different things but they are not working. Any suggestions will be highly appreciated.

Comment: More information needed. What is your input `youtubelink` and what is the output HTML of it?

Comment: Missing a closing `>` in your `<iframe` tag.

Comment: that's not the issue, I've checked it

Comment: Have you checked the source code of that page and that the videolink in there is correct? Looks like you're adding `<br>` to the end, is that still a valid youtube link then?

Comment: yeah that was the issue, I resolved it. Thanks @kerbholz

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks everyone for suggestions, I found the issue. It's because the < br > tag also gets stored in the link due to which the video is not shown. Here:

```
foreach ($splittedstring as $key => $value) {


 $x[$key] = $value."<br>";  //Here was the issue


 }
```

Now its like this:

```
 foreach ($splittedstring as $key => $value) {


 $x[$key] = $value; //Corrected


 }
```